# htmlファイルを保存するとファイルのアイコンが勝手にChromeになってる

Tags: html, windows-10

index.htmlを保存すると、以下の画像の通りファイルの種類がChromeになってます。

これをEdgeやFirefoxとか別のものにするには、どうすればよいのでしょうか？
Windows10を使ってます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

設定→アプリ→既定のアプリ→ファイルの種類ごとに既定のアプリを選ぶ→.htmlの既定のアプリをクリックして変更

Comment: なるほど！　ありがとうございました。